# Group and Calculate number of days between (first and second) and (first and third) occurred an id inR

Tags: r, dataframe

how can i group and calculate number of days between (first and second) and (first and third) occurred an id in R,
for example i have below dataframe:

```
CRASH_DATE  geoid           CRASH_TIME  type
2015-12-10  123             1650        Fatal_i
2015-12-06  156             1722        Fatal_i
2015-12-10  123             1956        Fatal_i
2015-11-29  156             705         Fatal_i
2015-11-21  156             1756        Fatal_i
2015-12-10  123             1936        Fatal_i
2015-11-19  156             712         Fatal_i
2015-11-21  112             1706        Fatal_i
...
```

i want an output such as:

```
geoid   days_between(1,2)    days_between(1,3)
123     0                    0                 
156     2                    10                
112     Nan                  Nan                       
...
```

and this is my code:

```
 dt2  <- data.table(table)
 dt22 <- dt2[,list(diff1 = CRASH_DATE - shift(CRASH_TIME, fill = 
 first(CRASH_TIME)),diff2 = CRASH_DATE - shift(CRASH_TIME, fill = 
 first(CRASH_TIME))),by = c("geoid")]
```

but it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = "
CRASH_DATE  geoid           CRASH_TIME  type
2015-12-10  123             1650        Fatal_i
2015-12-06  156             1722        Fatal_i
2015-12-10  123             1956        Fatal_i
2015-11-29  156             705         Fatal_i
2015-11-21  156             1756        Fatal_i
2015-12-10  123             1936        Fatal_i
2015-11-19  156             712         Fatal_i
2015-11-21  112             1706        Fatal_i
", header=T)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(CRASH_DATE = ymd(CRASH_DATE)) %>%  # update to date variable (if needed)
  arrange(CRASH_DATE) %>%
  group_by(geoid) %>%
  summarise(days_between_1_2 = as.numeric(CRASH_DATE[2] - CRASH_DATE[1]),
            days_between_1_3 = as.numeric(CRASH_DATE[3] - CRASH_DATE[1]))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   geoid days_between_1_2 days_between_1_3
#   <int>            <dbl>            <dbl>
# 1   112               NA               NA
# 2   123                0                0
# 3   156                2               10
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using base R, `aggregate()`

```
df = read.table(text = 
  'CRASH_DATE  geoid           CRASH_TIME  type
  2015-12-10  123             1650        Fatal_i
  2015-12-06  156             1722        Fatal_i
  2015-12-10  123             1956        Fatal_i
  2015-11-29  156             705         Fatal_i
  2015-11-21  156             1756        Fatal_i
  2015-12-10  123             1936        Fatal_i
  2015-11-19  156             712         Fatal_i
  2015-11-21  112             1706        Fatal_i', 
  header=TRUE, 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$CRASH_DATE <- as.Date(df$CRASH_DATE)  # convert to date

df <- df[order(df$geoid, df$CRASH_DATE), ]  #sort by geoid, CRASH_DATE

# group by geoid, calculate cumsum(diff(df$CRASH_DATE):
aggregate( df$CRASH_DATE, 
           by=df["geoid"], 
           FUN=function(x) cumsum(as.integer(diff(x))))

  geoid         x
1   112          
2   123      0, 0
3   156 2, 10, 17
```

the anonymous function uses

- `cumsum()` the cumulative sum of
- `diff()` differences between each date

Comment: This solution has a benefit of automatically scaling for any number of repeated incidents.  I.e. `x` in the result will be a list as long as needed to include additional incidents. For example,  2, 10 and _17_ days for geoid 156.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer set - here is the data.table solution since you were using that originally-

```
setorderv(dt2, c('geoid','CRASH_DATE'), c(1, 1))
dt2[, date_order := 1:.N, by = c('geoid')]

dt2_wide = dcast(dt2, geoid ~ date_order, value.var = "CRASH_DATE")

dt2_wide[,days_between_1_2 := abs(`1` - `2`)]
dt2_wide[,days_between_1_3 := abs(`1` - `3`)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following in data.table style, prerequisite is CRASH_DATE column in Date format and dt as data.table object. I understand that you want the order unchanged, you want it "as is", the way it occured in file:

```
    dt[,.(days_between_1_2=.SD[2,CRASH_DATE]-.SD[1,CRASH_DATE],
          days_between_1_3=.SD[3,CRASH_DATE]-.SD[1,CRASH_DATE]),geoid]
```